# Error in Cassandra system.log: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: cassandra, cql3, nodetool

I am getting the following exception on a completely blank cluster on all nodes. There is absolutely nothing in there. There is no reason that I could gather.

```
INFO [FlushWriter:5] 2013-07-18 03:20:05,250 Memtable.java (line 495) Completed flushing /media/ephemeral0/cassandra/data/system/peers/system-peers-ic-7-Data.db (122 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372450799758, position=452016)
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:174] 2013-07-18 05:19:58,505 CassandraDaemon.java (line 175) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:174,1,main]
FSWriteError in /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createTempFile(FileUtils.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$Writer.tempCacheFile(AutoSavingCache.java:295)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$Writer.saveCache(AutoSavingCache.java:254)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$10.run(CompactionManager.java:838)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1705)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1726)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1803)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createTempFile(FileUtils.java:88)
        ... 9 more
```

So, now when I see `nodetool info` on the node I see that both gossip and thrift is down.

```
Token            : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
ID               : 88016797-cd3e-44b6-8086-2dc3298760fb
Gossip active    : false
Thrift active    : false
Load             : 96.42 KB
Generation No    : 0
Uptime (seconds) : 1738289
Heap Memory (MB) : 1180.89 / 4016.00
Data Center      : us-west
Rack             : 1b
Exceptions       : 120
Key Cache        : size 2800 (bytes), capacity 104857600 (bytes), 340 hits, 365 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache        : size 0 (bytes), capacity 0 (bytes), 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
```

I could restart them without any issues from nodetool. Any clue?

Comment: Off topic for stackOverflow. Try [serverFault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 3):

"Permission denied" is your smoking gun.  Looks like the Cassandra doesn't have permission to write to the data directories you configured.